# Retorno metodo boolean de um observable

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um metodo que deve ser retornado um boleano de acordo com a resposta do service.

Não estou conseguindo retornar true ou falso fora do observable. Alguma dica?

```
checkPermission(route): boolean {
    let permissao = this.loginService
        .checkPermission(route)
        .subscribe(permission => {
            if (!permission[0]) {
                return false
            } else {
                return = true;
            }
        });

    return permissao;
}
```

Comment: Não vai conseguir mesmo, **permissao** é uma variável cujo valor é retornado de uma função assíncrona, quando faz **return permissao** o valor ainda não retornou da API.

Answer (score 1):

O `checkPermission` só invocará o conteúdo dentro do seu subscribe quando ele finalizar a tarefa que foi delegada a ele, por exemplo uma requisição. Veja que é um processo assíncrono, então o primeiro método `checkPermission(route): boolean ...` não poderá retornar um `boolean`.

Como você não postou o contexto vou deixar um exemplo:

```
// Quando o checkPermission for finalizado ele irá 
// dar um valor á variável permissaoRota
permissaoRota = false;
checkPermission(route): boolean {
    this.loginService
        .checkPermission(route)
        .subscribe(permission => {
            permissaoRota = !permission[0];
        });
}

 // No seu template:
<div *ngIf="permissaoRota">rota xyz</div<
```

Outro exemplo convertendo para Promise:

```
checkPermission(route): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.loginService
        // suponho que a função abaixo retorne um Observable<boolean>
        .checkPermission(route)
        .toPromise();
}

// Exemplo de como usar o método
async teste() {
    try {
        const permissaoRota = await checkPermission('minha rota');
    } catch(err) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o await para aguardar a resposta do serviço ou que seu método checkPermission() retorne um Observable< boolean >;